# Re-initialise Vuejs2 after ajax load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Have looked around and can't find a solution for this.

I have a .vue file which is loaded on a page, and the user can click a button which causes an ajax load on the page which replaces some content (including where the vue component is displayed).

The ajax call happens outside of Vue, replacing content which includes the vue component.

Once the ajax completes, the Vue component doesn't display. Is there a way I can manually re-initialise Vue?

Thanks

Comment: try `this.$forceUpdate()` when ajax call completes

Comment: thanks for the comment - unfortunately doesn't work, the ajax call happens outside of vuejs

Comment: So you're putting vue into a pre-existing app?

Comment: Its a laravel application that I've made a Vuejs component for. I'm putting the component tag on the page in the laravel template and loading the compiled vuejs javascript file. The component shows fine, then I do an ajax call to refresh some content outside of vuejs, but the component is in the content which gets replaced. I now need to reinitialise vue to restart the component.

Comment: @LukeP have you tried `Vue.nextTick()`. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick

Comment: No luck. I've made a gist of the Vue main.js file I'm using. I've attached the vue instance and vue to the window object to try and run nextTick from outside Vue. See https://gist.github.com/lukeparkinson/8949cde78d7c0de2cf07dbf113838e07

Comment: Your external call is replacing the *all* the DOM controlled by Vue, or just part of it?

Comment: i'm in same case, i'm trying add vuejs to a website working with jquery. i want to reload vuejs after a modal generated in backend is appeared.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best way, but it works just creating a new Vue instance (there might be a reason not to do this, I don't use Vue much).

I've done a short test here: https://jsfiddle.net/yazbx35d/

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
});

$('#app').empty().append($('<p></p>', {
    text: '{{newMessage}}'
}));

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    newMessage: 'Hello again Vue.js!'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you could create a separate Vue instance as an [Event Bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication), emit an event using it when the ajax call completes. Listen for the event inside the component or main Vue instance and update the component.

Create the bus:

```
var bus = new Vue()
```

When your ajax call resolves:

```
bus.$emit('update', 1)
```

Inside your main Vue instance/component:

```
bus.$on('update', function (id) {
  // ...
})
```